# Counting values in data frame subject to conditions

Tags: r

I have been searching around and I cannot figure out how to sumarise the data I have in my data frame (subject to some ranges). I know that it can be done when applying some combination of daaply/taaply or table but I haven't been able to get the exact result I was expecting.

Basically I want to turn this:

```
part_no val1 val2 val3
2 1 2 3 45.3
2 1 3 4 -12.3
3 1 3 4 99.3
3 1 5 2 -3.2
3 1 4 3 -55.3
```

Into this:

```
part_no val3_between0_50 val3_bw50_100 val3_bw-50_0 val3_bw-100_-50
2 1 0 0 1 0
3 0 1 0 1 1
```

This is dummy data, I got a lot more rows, but the idea is the same. I just want to count the number of values for a participant that meet certain condition.

If anyone could explain it sort of step by step, I would really appreciate it. I saw lots of different little posts around, but none do exactly this and my attempts only got me half way there. Like using `table`, etc.

Comment: If you provide your data in a more easily reporducible format, the question is quicker for others to answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: In the meantime, take a look at the `cut` function.

Comment: @RichieCotton thanks, I didn't know how to format the question so I just put in codeblocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution that the one below (will not need the extra row used below although if you wanted to move the renaming code to this matrix result, you could):

```
xtabs(~part_no +cut(val4, breaks=c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100) ), dat=dat)
 #-------------
       cut(val4, breaks = c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100))
part_no (-100,-50] (-50,0] (0,50] (50,100]
      2          0       1      1        0
      3          1       1      0        1
```

---

First try: .... n to a slightly different problem and would be easy to adapt to your situation. The difficulty I ran into is that my solution requires the part_no to start with 1. You could assign row labels later I suppose. Or make 'part_no' a factor and use its numeric-mode value.

```
 dat <- read.table(text="part_no val1 val2 val3 val4
 1 1 2 3 -32
 2 1 2 3 45.3
 2 1 3 4 -12.3
 3 1 3 4 99.3
 3 1 5 2 -3.2
 3 1 4 3 -55.3
 ", head=T)

levs= 4; recs <- matrix( c(unique(dat$part_no), 
                           rep(0, levs*length(unique(dat$part_no))) ), 
                        nrow=length(unique(dat$part_no)) )
 recs[ cbind( dat$part_no, 
              1+ findInterval(dat$val4, c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100) ) )] <- 1
 recs
#------------------------------------
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    0
[2,]    2    0    1    1    0
[3,]    3    1    1    0    1
#------------------------------------
 colnames(recs) <- c(names(dat)[1] , 
                     paste("val_btwn", 
                            c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100)[1:4], 
                            c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100)[2:5], 
                            sep="_") )
 recs
#------------------------------------
     part_no val_btwn_-100_-50 val_btwn_-50_0 val_btwn_0_50 val_btwn_50_100
[1,]       1                 0              1             0               0
[2,]       2                 0              1             1               0
[3,]       3                 1              1             0               1
```

And now that I think further I might use `cut` and `xtabs` next time. In fact it worked so well I am going to post it on top.